# Android- How to get JSON values from string

Tags: android, json, string

I have three strings. Following the value of `String a;`:

```
{"a":"value","b":"value"}
```

And the value of `String b;`:

```
[{"a":"value","b":"value"},{"c":"value","d":"value"}]
```

And the value of `String c;`:

```
[[{"a":"value","b":"value"},{"c":"value","d":"value"}],[{"e":"value2","f":"value"},{"g":"value2","h":"value"}]]
```

How to get the value of `a` of `String a;`, the value of `a` and `c` of `String b;` and `a`, `d`, `f` and `h` of `String c;` through JSON without use libraries beyond those already available?

Comment: Use library like GSON https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide.

Comment: I want to do it without use libraries beyond those already available.

Comment: Take a look at: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: I've already read it, I asked this question because I did not understand much.

Comment: Try this to get value "a" from json string c: JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(c); 
String a = jObj.getString("a");

Comment: @mayr thanks you a lot, can you solve the mine other two examples in a answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html). For json String a:

```
JSONObject aObj = new JSONObject(a); 
String a = jObj.getString("a");
String b = jObj.getString("b");
```

Json string b:

```
JSONArray bArr = new JSONArray(b);
JSONObject first = bArr.getJSONObject(0);
```

Json string c:

```
JSONArray cArr = new JSONArray(b);
JSONArray innerArr = cArr.getJSONArray(0);
JSONObject first = innerArr.getJSONObject(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the GSON parser. See http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html or many other resources

Comment: How to do it without using a library?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java or http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm or https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples or many others.